# Revert Project in Symfony to dev mode

Tags: symfony

I turned my project in symfony2 into production mode. I followed the instructions of the [manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) of symfony2. My Question is: How do I revert this step? How do I turn my application back to dev mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct "Development Mode" in the Standard Installation. You have to use the app_dev.php to enter the Development Environment.

Comment: ah... I see. if i add /app_dev.php/ in front of my URLs I enter the other enviroment. Wow thanks for that quick answer ^^.